# JNDI: EJB not found

Tags: jboss, ejb, jndi

I deployed a session bean called `SessionServiceBean` on my Jboss As 7.1 server. At deployment I get the following output in the console listening the correct JNDI identifiers for that bean:

```
JNDI bindings for session bean named SessionServiceBean in deployment unit subdeployment "account-ejb.jar" of deployment "replay-ear.ear" are as follows:

java:global/replay-ear/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService
java:app/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService
java:module/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService
java:jboss/exported/replay-ear/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService
java:global/replay-ear/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean
java:app/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean
java:module/SessionServiceBean
```

Now if i try to lookup the bean in my JUnit Test Case:

```
service = (SessionService) jndiCtx.lookup("java:global/replay-ear/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService");
```

I get an exception telling me that the server cant find the bean:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global/replay-ear/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global.replay-ear.account-ejb."SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I dont understand this error as the jndi identifier matchs the one outputted in the log and my client is for sure connected to the right server.

Could it be that the user Im using for authentication doesnt have the required rights for the jndi lookup? I actually have no clue why this is not working. Thats my first time working with remote ejbs.

Answer (score 0):

Apperently the error was keeping the `java:global` in the JNDI identifier.

The working lookup now looks like this:

```
service = (SessionService) jndiCtx.lookup("/replay-ear/account-ejb/SessionServiceBean!de.replay.account.SessionService");
```